# How make http.globalAgent.maxSockets works on expressjs?

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, express

I see number of posts on this platform giving the same solution which does not work for me, so here is my very simple node program I would like to understand why it still appears to process requests 6 by 6 instead of what I setup in `http.globalAgent.maxSockets` ?

```
var http = require('http');

http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 10;

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use('/', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('Request /');

    setTimeout(function(){
        res.send('ok');
        console.log('Handled');
    }, 2000);
});

app.listen(3309);

console.log('Server up.');
```

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my problem was the client used to execute request: Google Chrome
Chrome has a 6 connexion per host limitation. So neither node/angular or some other framework is concerned by this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what problem you try to solve, but `http.globalAgent` is a singleton http **client**, so it can't affect your code in any way.

Comment: You are right. I just anwser my question because my problem was really far away from that.